# How to handle multiple fonts for multiple languages in spa appliction

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular5

In my angular 5 application I develop for multiple countries say, India(Hindi), default(english) and Malaysia.

Now when the user change the language, I require to add the appropriate `font-family` as default to page.

In the page, there is some `font-family` added by `element` level. say ( p tag with font thinner and small size ).

As a information how this kind of scenario handled by UI development?
Is there any regular practice which i need to follow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your framework, many allow for inbuilt localization functionality that makes it super easy to change content as well as things like font. For Angular look into:

https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/2015/01/translation-localization-angularjs